# Auditing Remote Desktop Access on Windows Server from Ubuntu Tunnel Host

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, remote-desktop, rdp

Usecase :

I have a tunnel host that is Ubuntu-based. Where the user identifies itself using their ssh key. Then it can access a remote desktop session, which is a single-user session named WebApp. Tunnel host has separate users, so it is possible for us to keep track of who took their tunnel host session using ssh keys. But for Windows rdp sessions, it's hard to keep track of who logged in to the Windows server.

Required:

Is there any way to monitor who accesses the Windows server using a remote desktop protocol?

Note:

I don't want to implement Active Directory, AWS SSO, or any other additional AWS resource.